Maths Olympiad question help on algebraic analysis on factors

Given that $N$ is not a square number and it has $m$ factors, express the sum of all $\smash{\frac{1}{f - \sqrt{N}}}$, where $f$ is a factor of $N$, in terms of $m$ and $N$.

I was thinking about representing each $f$ as $N$ divided by all other $f$s, but it doesn't work too well, not to mention there's no LCM.

Maybe you want to pair up $f$ with $n/f.$ Just a guess, though.

@ThomasAndrews, was just about to write that, and your guess will indeed lead to a nice simplification.

Notice that since $N$ is not a square, each divisor $a$ of $N$ has a distinct complementary divisor $b$, in the sense that $ab = N$. In the case of a square, say $n^2 = N$, then the $n$ is its own complementary divisor. But this possibility is ruled out in the problem statement.
What does the sum look like for just these two terms? And can you simplify it? (Only reveal the calculation once you've tried it yourself!)

 $$ \begin{aligned} \frac{1}{a - \sqrt{N}} + \frac{1}{b - \sqrt{N}} &= \frac{1}{a - \sqrt{ab}} + \frac{1}{b - \sqrt{ba}} \\ &= \frac{1}{(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b})\sqrt{a}} + \frac{1}{(\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a})\sqrt{b}} \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}} \biggl( \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}} \biggr) \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}} \biggl( \frac{\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{ab}} \biggr) \\ &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \end{aligned} $$

Happily, this doesn't depend on $a$ or $b$, so it applies to each factor pair. I leave to you the last step of finding the entire sum.

Simpler scaling your LHS by $,-\sqrt N=-\sqrt{ab},$ it's just $,\dfrac{1}{1-c}+\dfrac{1}{1-c^{-1}} = 1,,\ c = \sqrt{a/b}\ \ $

Thank you for your layout btw, I like having the tips only. Many thanks again
